# Serial Port Synchronization in Delphi

Tags: delphi, serial-port

I am still having issues with the TComPort component but this time is not the component itself is the logic behind it. I have a device witch sends some ascii strings via serial port i need to prase those strings the problem is the computer reacts very fast so in the event char it captures only a part of the string the rest of the string comes back later... so parsing it when it is recived makes it impossible.

I was thinking in writing a timer witch verify if there was no serial activity 10 secons or more and then prase the string that i am saving into a buffer. But this method is unprofessional isn't there a idle event witch i can listen...Waiting for the best solution for my problem. Thanks.

Comment: This is a known issue. Had it on more environments. The data event trigger is indeed quicker than the data that is following. Am not sure that there is anything else, besides a small wait before reading.

Comment: This is quite normal, and you should simply store the characters in a buffer, and reset a timer. Then use a timer to trigger the actual activity - the timer can be quite tight. You want to end up with a "state machine" and have triggers for the events.

Comment: Assume you use Djean Crnila's et al TComport (several components are called 'TComport'). This issue might be related to the data event trigger but also possible the baud rate of your serial device is set to a rate different from the rate of your comport control.  If your device sends packets once every few ms, you should easily be able to capture and parse the entire data packet if the packet is a reasonable length.  Does the device send an end of packet control character? -makes it easier. If you provide a more info about the device, received packet etc. someone might be able to provide help.

Comment: writing a packet component is not that hard. all data from the event goes into to buffer and the packet analyses the buffer, depending on your needs you could have a startcondition, endcondition and so on...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After using a number of serial-port-components, I've got the best results until now, by using `CreateFile('\\?\COM1',GENERIC_READ or GENERIC_WRITE,0,nil,OPEN_EXISTING,     FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,0)`, passing that handle to a THandleStream instance, and starting a dedicated thread to read from it. I know threads take a little more work than writing an event handler, but it still is the best way to handle any synchronization issues that arise from using serial ports.

Answer (score 3):

Typical handler for OnRXChar event:

```
procedure XXX.RXChar(Sender: TObject; Count: Integer);
begin
  ComPort.ReadStr(s, Count);
  Accumulator := Accumulator + s;
  if not AccumContainsPacketStart then
    Accumulator := ''
  else if AccumContainsPacketEndAfterStart then begin
    ExtractFullStringFromAccum;
    ParseIt;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: the string contains characters such as #0 so readstr method use is defenetly out of the.question

Comment: It is not important for pascal strings (until the output by OS functions)

Comment: @opc0de, in pascal the #0 character is like any other character. If you prefer working with bytes, swap the AnsiChars/AnsiStrings to Bytes/TBytes. This is the preferred way since D2009 and unicode.

Comment: See [Reading binary data from serial port using Dejan TComport Delphi component](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2458219/576719) for an example, but as MBo says, there is no fundamental difference between `TComPort.Read( var buffer; Count:Integer)` and `TComPort.ReadStr( var Str:AnsiStr; count:Integer)`.

Answer (score 2):

**Note.** 
Most com-port components do not have a clue when to report back to the owner. Normally the thread that is responsible to gather the bytes from the port is informed by the OS that one or more bytes are ready to be processed. This information is then simply popped up to your level. So when you expect the message to be transferred, you get what the OS is giving you.

You have to buffer all incoming characters in a global buffer. When you get the final character in your message string, handle the message.

Here is an example where the message start is identified with a special character and the end of the message is identified with another character.

If your message is constructed in another way, I'm sure you can figure out how to adapt the code.

```
var
  finalBuf: AnsiString;

{- Checking message }
Function ParseAndCheckMessage(const parseS: AnsiString) : Integer;
begin
  Result := 0; // Assume ok
  {- Make tests to confirm a valid message }
  ...
end;


procedure TMainForm.ComPortRxChar(Sender: TObject; Count: Integer);
var
  i,err: Integer;
  strBuf: AnsiString;
begin
  ComPort.ReadStr(strBuf, Count);
  for i := 1 to Length(strBuf) do
    case strBuf[i] of
      '$' : 
        finalBuf := '$';  // Start of package
      #10 :
        begin
          if (finalBuf <> '') and (finalBuf[1] = '$') then  // Simple validate check 
            begin
              SetLength( finalBuf, Length(finalBuf) - 1); // Strips CR
              err := ParseAndCheckMessage(finalBuf);
              if (err = 0) then 
                {- Handle validated string }
              else
                {- Handle error } 
            end;
          finalBuf := '';
        end; 
    else
      finalBuf := finalBuf + strBuf[i];  
    end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

If your protocol has begin/end markers, you can use TComDataPacket to provide you full packets, when they are available.

Comment: i recive an access violation when i use TComDataPacket in Delphi 7 not all the time but when the packet is bigger

Comment: OK, I saw Warren to speak against it in your other question. We just used it with success in Delphi XE2, though.

Comment: It seems to define a fixed buffer with size 1024 bytes. Try to increase it in the constructor and see if that helps with bigger packets.

Answer (score -2):

For certain amount of character we can use delay some miliseconds before ReadStr to make sure the data is completely sent. Example for 4 amount of character:

```
procedure TForm1.ComPort1RxChar(Sender: TObject; Count: Integer);
var
  Str: String;
  tegangan : real;
begin
  sleep(100); //delay for 100ms
  ComPort1.ReadStr(Str, 4);
```

...