# Serial communication in delphi 7 not fully received

Tags: delphi, serial-port, arduino

I have a Delphi code that receives sensor values from an arduino. The value received by Delphi is 4 character long string. For example 0.04; 0,32; 0,28 etc. But sometimes the value is not received fully. Only 1 character that displayed like 4;33;2 etc. When it should be  0.04; 0,32; 0,28.
This is the code I wrote in Delphi 7:

```
procedure TForm1.ComPort1RxChar(Sender: TObject; Count: Integer);
var
  Str: String;
  tegangan: real;
begin
  DecimalSeparator:='.';
  sleep(25);
  ComPort1.ReadStr(Str, 4);
if Str <> '' then
begin
  Edit1.Text:=Str;
  tegangan:=strtofloat(Edit1.Text);
  x := x + 1;
  with chart1 do
    with series1 do
      addxy(x,tegangan);
      Adotable1.Open;
      AdoTable1.Append;
      AdoTable1.FieldByName('Arus').AsString:=Edit1.Text;
      AdoTable1.FieldByName('Waktu').AsString:=formatdatetime('dd/mm/yyyy'+'hh:nn:ss',now);
      AdoTable1.Post;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: You're probably reading before the device finished sending. You might get more help, if you need it, if you format your code and ask a question.

Answer (score 2):

You are assuming `ReadStr()` returns everything you asked for.  The `Count` parameter of the `OnRxChar` event tells you how many bytes are actually available.  If the numbers are always 4 characters, try something more like this instead (similar to the answers provided in the [other discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10550745/) that you commented on):

```
var
  Buffer: AnsiString;

procedure TForm1.ComPort1RxChar(Sender: TObject; Count: Integer);
var
  Str: AnsiString;
  tegangan : Real;
begin
  ComPort1.ReadStr(Str, Count);
  Buffer := Buffer + Str;

  while Length(Buffer) >= 4 do
  begin
    Str := Copy(Buffer, 1, 4);
    Delete(Buffer, 1, 4);

    Edit1.Text := Str;

    DecimalSeparator := '.';
    tegangan := StrToFloat(Str);
    Inc(x);

    chart1.series1.addxy(x, tegangan);

    AdoTable1.Open;
    AdoTable1.Append;
    AdoTable1.FieldByName('Arus').AsString := Str;
    AdoTable1.FieldByName('Waktu').AsString := FormatDateTime('dd/mm/yyyyhh:nn:ss', Now);
    AdoTable1.Post;
  end;
end;
```