# How to convert hexadecimal data (stored in a string variable) to an integer value

Tags: delphi, serial-port, buffer, delphi-5, tcomport

## Edit (abstract)

I tried to interpret `Char`/`String` data as `Byte`, 4 bytes at a time. This was because I could only get `TComport`/`TDatapacket` to interpret streamed data as String, not as any other data type. I still don't know how to get the `Read` method and `OnRxBuf` event handler to work with TComport.

## Problem Summary

I'm trying to get data from a mass spectrometer (MS) using some Delphi code. The instrument is connected with a serial cable and follows the RS232 protocol. I am able to send commands and process the text-based outputs from the MS without problems, but I am having trouble with interpreting the data buffer.

## Background

From the user manual of this instrument:

> "With the exception of the ion current values, the output of the RGA are ASCII character strings terminated by a linefeed + carriage return terminator. Ion signals are represented as integers in units of 10^-16 Amps, and transmitted directly in **hex format (four byte integers, 2's complement format, Least Significant Byte first) for maximum data throughput.**"

I'm not sure whether **(1)** hex data can be stored properly in a string variable. I'm also not sure how to **(2)** implement 2's complement in Delphi and **(3)** the Least Significant Byte first.

Comment: The only place you can ever store hexadecimal is in a string. That's because hexadecimal is a textual representation of a number. Perhaps what you really have though is binary data, i.e. an array of bytes, and that's what you mean when you refer to as hexadecimal.

Comment: Fair enough, but am I correct in assuming that I should convert the "string" that I'm getting from the OnPacket event to an Array of Byte to go forward?

Comment: I've really no idea. I can't understand much of the question. I don't see any code that appears to have anything to do with hexadecimal though.

Comment: Basically, I'm getting 4 bytes of data from the instrument at a time, but the event handler stores it in a string. I want to convert that string to an integer value, but I'm getting strings like "æ" and so forth. So I gotta figure out how to convert this to an array of byte to move forward.

Comment: So don't read into a string. Call the `Read` method instead. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2458219/  Seriously I urge you to step back, slow down, and spend some time really trying to understand the difference between binary and text, and what hexadecimal really is. It's very important that you are clear on this.

Comment: I forgot about that option, thanks David!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following @David Heffernan 's advice, I went and revised my data types. Attempting to harvest binary data from characters doesn't work, because not all values from 0-255 can be properly represented. You lose data along the way, basically. Especially it your data is represented 4 bytes at a time.

The solution for me was to use the Async Professional component instead of Denjan's Comport lib. It handles datastreams better and has a built-in log that I could use to figure out how to interpret streamed resposes from the instrument. It's also better documented. So, if you're new to serial communications (like I am), rather give that a go.